# Is Cersei Lannister menopausal?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In "Two Swords" (*Game of Thrones*, S04E01), Qyburn asks Cersei whether her "symptoms" had gotten better. When Jaime asks her about this, she refuses to tell him. They then engage in an argument in which Cersei tells him that he has arrived "too late". At the time, I assumed it was because she is engaged to Loras Tyrell but I wonder if that's not the only reason.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realise she was so young. I'm pretty sure that's not the same in the show though because Olenna and Tywin discuss the danger that she is menopausal over the wedding plans.

Comment: Fair enough. Still Tywin did have a discussion with Olenna because Olenna was worried that Cersei was menopausal.

Comment: You are forgetting that she had a child before Joffery. Anyway she had been we'd to Robert Baratheon for seventeen years at the start of the show. She says that she was very happy to wed Robert at the time, if you are right then she would have been sixteen, which makes it doubtful that she would have been willing to marry anyone, especially considering her relationship with Jaime.

Comment: I'll say this it again. westerns.org is according to the books, not the show. Robert Baratheon had a true born son long before Joffery was born but he was poisoned by Cersei in infancy. I'm geussing it's been a while since you actually watched the show ;-)

Comment: She is 41 at the start of the show. It says so right here. http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Cersei_Lannister. That makes her currently 44, not an unlikely age for menopause.

Comment: @MartinSchröder In S04E01, Joffrey mentions that Jaime is a "40-year-old knight".

Comment: Cersei is mental, that's what she is!

Comment: She's sleeping around and Qyburn is seeing to her pregnancy symptoms, possibly even giving her an abortifacient (a drug to cause an abortion). I think the scene serves to hint the audience at a split between Jaime and Cersei, as well as to explain to the audience why Cersei very quickly trusts Qyburn. The books make this very obvious in a way that the show doesn't, unfortunately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't think this is ever made explicit.  I can think of several possible explanations:

1. Cersei is pregnant and experiencing something akin to morning sickness. Jaime is too late in the sense that Cersei has found other lovers.  I think this is the most likely scenario.  That the symptoms go away indicates either she wasn't really pregnant or Kyburn helped effect an abortion.
2. Cersei became infected with a sexually transmitted disease for the same reasons mentioned above.
3. Cersei is going through menopause as you mentioned, or is perhaps faking menopause to get out of her engagement with Ser Loras (this wouldn't make as much sense since the symptoms seem to abate).
4. Some other illness, and it was only mentioned because Jaime would be jealous that a non-maester touched her.

Answer (score 6):

### Not yet

In the episode [*Eastwatch*](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Eastwatch), she reveals to Jamie that she's pregnant.

Comment: Well... she _tells_ Jaime that she's pregnant. We don't know yet if it's true. The fact that she was meeting with Qyburn moments before does point in her favour, though.

Comment: @Llewellyn exactly what I thought when I saw Jaime interrupting this meeting with Qyburn!

Comment: It also fits her character to try to outrun her prophecy by having a new kid after her three prophecy children died. If she lied, it'd be a very cheap stunt from the writing team. It's also true that the books support that she's very much sexually active and then the show's scene with Qyburn in S04E01 might suggest he's helping her to abort a pregnancy.

Comment: Your video link is dead.

Comment: @Randal'Thor hi, thanks. I have limited access these days. If you have another link feel free to replace. Regards